# Visual Studio 2017 and SSIS 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, visual-studio-2017, ssis-2008

Hi there is a way to create DTSX packages for SSIS in SQL Server 2008 R2 using Visual Studio 2017?
Many Thanks